# How to prevent Confirm Form Resubmission on page refresh with PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, header

I am trying to get rid of the Confirm Form Resubmission alert that appears after the page is refreshed in Chrome.

```
if ($input === "hello") {
    include("hello.php");
    header('Location: ./');
}
```

**Process**
There is an input field and if the user types `hello` and hits enter, `hello.php` will be included in the page.

This works perfectly, however as a result, the user will receive a "Confirm Form Resubmission" alert when refreshing the page. I added the `header` in order to prevent this though it doesn't seem to redirect (I have also tried changing the URL within `header`).

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Try to use echo "<script>window.location.href='/';</script>";die; instead of header()

Comment: @NikolayGanovski Great, works perfectly, thank you!